# Android Device Manager fails to start device

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I was trying to test a xamarin app on an emulated android device so I set up hyperV, created the device and started it. However, as seen below, it fails to boot and it's unclear to me as to why. I'm guessing this has to do with hyperV but really not sure.

[image: post device-start screenshot]

Update: After leaving it running for a bit it popped up the following:

> Emulator error
>
> Device error: Could not get emulator name after starting AVD pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28

Comment: First of all, please Open SDKs and Tools, check if you have Android emulator need to update like following screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/CczmO75, If so, please update it, And check the settings in this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?pivots=windows#accelerating-with-hyper-v

Comment: I've already got the emulator installed at the latest version. Also settings match those specified in the doc.

Comment: Did you install Android studio in your PC? If so, you can create and open a emulator in Android studio, if you can run it normally.

Comment: Well I'm developing on VS so it would be nice to have the emulator there as well. That solution would be my last resort.

Comment: You can test it with AS, If you use same SDK between AS and VS, If you can open the emulator in AS, you can running normally in VS as well.